# Google Cloud App Engine Cron Service Interruption

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I set up a cron job yesterday at 12pm to run every minute. See below for the code from my cron.yaml file.

```
cron:
- description: Push a "tick" onto pubsub every minute.
  url: /publish/minute-tick
  schedule: every 1 minutes from 00:00 to 23:00
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 3
```

I'm relying heavily on this cron for scheduling purposes in my application. It troubles me because a few hours after setting up the cron I saw a 1 hour drop in service (6-7pm). I've scoured the logs but there is no explanation for this.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Log Entries during dropoff time

[image]

### Questions

1. Does anyone know why this dropoff would occur? If so is there a place in the appengine dashboard I can find an explanation.
2. Is running a 1 minute cron 24 hours a reliable thing to do in appengine? Everywhere I read then mention crons are for hourly, weekly and less frequent jobs. If you have any article suggestions for minutley crons in or outside of Google App Engine please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the problem:

```
  schedule: every 1 minutes from 00:00 to 23:00
```

You missed an hour in your schedule!  I suspect time zone differences caused the drop from 6-7pm.

Comment: Aaa. Thanks Jeff. I had that schedule for a previous cron that ran hourly. But now that it's every minute I need to account for minutes between 23:00 and 00:00